Laplace Transform of Derivative by Limit and Dirac Delta Distribution
The Laplace Transformation of the Derivative is given by
$\mathcal{L}[f'(x)](s) = \int_0^\infty f'(x) e^{-s x} dx = s \mathcal{L}[f(x)](s) - f(0)$, which can be easily shown by partial integration.
I want to derive this with other methods:
First, by using the Definition of the Derivative and
Secondly, by utilzing the Derivative of the Dirac Delta Distribution.
1.
$
\mathcal{L}[f'(x)](s) = \int_0^\infty \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{f(x+h) -f(x)}{h} e^{-s x} dx = \\ \lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{h} (\int_0^\infty f(x+h) e^{-s x} dx - \int_0^\infty f(x+h) e^{-s x} dx)  = \\
\lim_{h\rightarrow0} \frac{1}{h}(e^{hs}-1)\mathcal{L}[f(x)](s) = s \mathcal{L}[f(x)](s) 
$
Now this is obviously false. My questions are now, when can I interchange the limit and the integral. Shouldn't it suffice for the difference quotient to be limited, and this should be given. The other steps are linearity of Laplace transformation and the shifting property.
I fear the error arises hear as the shifting property is only for one direction, but how do I get the $f(0)$ part, when shifting to the other side?
2.
$
\mathcal{L}[f'(x)](s) = \int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta'(x-t) f(t) dt \,e^{-s x} dx \\= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{0}^{\infty}\delta'(x-t) e^{-s x} dx \,f(t) dt \\= \int_{-\infty}^\infty (e^{-st}(-\delta(t) + s\theta(t)) \,f(t) dt \\=
-\int_{\infty}^\infty e^{-st} \,\delta(t) f(t) dt +s \int^{\infty}_0 (e^{-st}\,f(t) dt =  -f(0) + s \mathcal{L}[f(x)](s)
$
Here I simply wish to know if there are lacking assumptions and if this proof is correct.
It may be useful to know that I used an additional Heaviside $\theta$ to calculate the first integral, where I then calculated the negated derivative of $\theta(x)e^{-sx}$ with $\theta'(x) = \delta(x)$.
I hope you can find the error in the first derivation (that I believe should work for example for the Fourier transformation) and any gaps in my second calculation.
Thanks!

For the first part, the Dominated Convergence Theorem guarantees that we may  interchange the order of the limit and integral in the following developemnt.    Proceeding, we have
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\{f'\}(s)&=\int_0^\infty f'(x)e^{-sx}\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^\infty \lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)e^{-sx}\,dx\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\left(\int_0^\infty f(x+h)e^{-sx}\,dx-\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx\right)\tag1\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\left(\int_h^\infty f(x)e^{-s(x-h)}\,dx-\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx\right)\tag2\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\left(\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-s(x-h)}\,dx-\int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx\right)\\\\
&-\underbrace{\lim_{h\to 0}\frac1h\int_0^h f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx}_{=f(0)}\\\\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{e^{sh}-1}h\right) \int_0^\infty f(x)e^{-sx}\,dx-f(0)\\\\
&=s\mathscr{L}\{f\}(s)-f(0)
\end{align}$$
Note that in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we enforced the substitution $x\mapsto x-h$ in the first integral of $(1)$.  Upon doing so, the lower limit of the implicated integral in $(2)$ is equal to $h$, and not to $0$.  That was the error in the posted question's solution.

For the second part of the question, the issue is that the product of distributions is not defined in general.  That is, the distribution $\theta\delta'$ is not well defined.  Therefore, the manipulations that led to the expression
$$\int_0^\infty \delta'(x-t)e^{-sx}\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x-t)\theta(x)e^{-sx}\,dx$$
are not rigorously justifiable.  However, if one proceeds heuristically, then one would be tempted to write
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x-t)\theta(x)e^{-sx}\,dx&=-\left.\left(\theta(x)e^{-sx}\right)\right|_{x=t}\\\\
&=s\theta(t)e^{-st}-\delta(t)e^{-st}
\end{align}$$
So, while this leads to the correct result, it is not rigorously justifiable in the context of distribution theory.

After (2) you split the integral in two (I believe the limit to infinity is a writing error?); I see how this manipulation gives us the desired result, I simply used the shifting property as a result without thinking about the underlying substitution. Thanks! Why isn't $\theta \delta'$ well defined, shouldn't it be defined by the integral you given below? Or is a possible evaluation the dirac delta or the heaviside theta at x=0 the problem?

@theta_phi Ah, good catch.  The limit to infinity was a typographical error.  I've edited accordingly.  Thank you. ;-)  The issue is that the product of distributions is not generally defined.  And $\theta$ is not a suitable test function since it is not $C_C^\infty$.

And please feel free to up vote and accept an answer are you see fit. ;-))
